# Why would a GET variable one one page of a site cause a 404 error when a GET variable works on another page of a site?

Tags: php, html, 404-error

For example  I have 20 pages on a site.  one of them is called bacon another called eggs. on the same site...lets say breakfast.com

I have the permalinks set up properly and have used them successfully on all pages, including Eggs by way of this:
www.breakfast.com/eggs?cooked=scrambled.
This works 100% as it should.

However, on a different page of Breakfast.com called sausage...this, does not work.
www.breakfast.com/sausage?type=spicy

this is causes a 404 error.  I don't see why it would as it's the same format.  I have verified that the page exists in my pages directory in WP-admin.

If I strip away the GET variable the page works.  Google is not helping me.  Anyone have a similar experience?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WordPress has a list of reserved terms that you *cannot* use for taxonomies.  From your question, I gather that "cooked" is a taxonomy that applies to eggs and "type" is a taxonomy that applies to sausage.  Unfortunately, "type" is a reserved term in WordPress, so it interprets your query string differently than you expect.

The full list of reserved terms is available [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms).  Just use a different term ... maybe "sausage-type" ... for your taxonomy and you should be in the clear.

Comment: EAMann, When I found that this was my problem I almost fell out of my chair both almost crying and laughing at the same time.  I would have NEVER thought about that.  Thank you SO SO much.

Comment: Just saved my evening!

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing inconsistent behavior with query parameters until I registered the parameter with Wordpress, like this:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = "cooked";
        return $vars;
    }
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

See more here: [get_query_var in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)